# I want to exception handle 'list index out of range.'

Tags: python, list, exception

I am using **BeautifulSoup** and parsing some HTMLs.

I'm getting a certain data from each HTML *(using for loop)* and adding that data to a certain list.

The problem is, some of the HTMLs have different format *(and they don't have the data that I want in them)*.

So, I was trying to use exception handling and add value `null` to the list *(I should do this since the sequence of data is important.)*

For instance, I have a code like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(links)
dlist = soup.findAll('dd', 'title')
# I'm trying to find content between <dd class='title'> and </dd>
gotdata = dlist[1]
# and what i want is the 2nd content of those
newlist.append(gotdata)
# and I add that to a newlist
```

and some of the links don't have any `<dd class='title'>`, so what I want to do is add string `null` to the list instead.

The error appears:

```
list index out of range.
```

What I have done tried is to add some lines like this:

```
if not dlist[1]:  
   newlist.append('null')
   continue
```

But it doesn't work out. It still shows error:

```
list index out of range.
```

What should I do about this? Should I use exception handling? or is there any easier way?

Any suggestions? Any help would be really great!

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Handling the exception is the way to go:

```
try:
    gotdata = dlist[1]
except IndexError:
    gotdata = 'null'
```

Of course you could also check the `len()` of `dlist`; but handling the exception is more intuitive.

Answer (score 47):

You have two options; either handle the exception or test the length:

```
if len(dlist) > 1:
    newlist.append(dlist[1])
    continue
```

or

```
try:
    newlist.append(dlist[1])
except IndexError:
    pass
continue
```

Use the first if there *often* is no second item, the second if there *sometimes* is no second item.

Answer (score 33):

A ternary will suffice. change:

```
gotdata = dlist[1]
```

to

```
gotdata = dlist[1] if len(dlist) > 1 else 'null'
```

this is a shorter way of expressing

```
if len(dlist) > 1:
    gotdata = dlist[1]
else: 
    gotdata = 'null'
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone interested in a shorter way:

```
gotdata = len(dlist)>1 and dlist[1] or 'null'
```

But for best performance, I suggest using `False` instead of `'null'`, then a one line test will suffice:

```
gotdata = len(dlist)>1 and dlist[1]
```

Comment: This style was common before python introduced conditional expressions (`v = a if condition else b`), but has been out of style for many years.

Answer (score 3):

Taking reference of ThiefMaster♦ sometimes we get an error with value given as '\n' or null and perform for that required to handle ValueError:

Handling the exception is the way to go

```
try:
    gotdata = dlist[1]
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    gotdata = 'null'
```

Comment: When would you ever get a `ValueError` from this?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range (1, len(list))
    try:
        print (list[i])

    except ValueError:
        print("Error Value.")
    except indexError:
        print("Erorr index")
    except :
        print('error ')
```

Comment: beware of the tab,
Python 3