# Scrapy: ERROR: Spider error processing

Tags: python, scrapy

i am new in python & scrapy. 
i tried to run existing code, but i got this error on every address:

```
>     2015-07-02 01:52:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g187147-d197524-r281927613-Hotel_Mirific_Opera-Paris_Ile_de_France.html>
> (referer:
> http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187147-d197524-Reviews-Hotel_Mirific_Opera-Paris_Ile_de_France.html)2015-07-02
> 01:52:19 
>     [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g187147-d197524-r281927613-Hotel_Mirific_Opera-Paris_Ile_de_France.html>
> (referer:
> http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187147-d197524-Reviews-Hotel_Mirific_Opera-Paris_Ile_de_France.html)
> 
    > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
    > "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line
    > 102, in iter_errback
    >     yield next(it)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py",
    > line 28, in process_spider_output
    >     for x in result:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py",
    > line 22, in <genexpr>
    >     return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py",
    > line 37, in <genexpr>
    >     return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py",
    > line 54, in <genexpr>
    >     return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line
    > 67, in _parse_response
    >     cb_res = callback(response, **cb_kwargs) or ()   File "/home/talmosko/Documents/scrapy/tripAdvisor/spiders/tripAdvisor.py",
    > line 30, in parse_item
    >      item['state'] =  hxs.xpath('//*[@id="PAGE"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/span/text()').extract()[0].encode('ascii',
    > errors='ignore')
    > 
    > IndexError: list index out of range
```

this is my code:
http://pastebin.com/XzM5DrDD

What is the problem? it seems like the spide didnt get an answer..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access an element that doesn't exist, the error is in this line

```
item['state'] =  hxs.xpath('//*[@id="PAGE"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/span/text()').extract()[0].encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

Problably

```
item['state'] =  hxs.xpath('//*[@id="PAGE"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/span/text()').extract()
```

is empty and you are trying to access the first element. You have two options:

- Modify the selector so it always return some data, it could be a good idea to test it with the [Scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)
- [Try and catch the IndexError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902480/263989)

Comment: the problem is not that i got nothing as response?

Comment: You are writing an scraper, in the same site some pages could have a piece of information while others don't. I won't check if all the pages in tripadvisor have 'state'