# Ignoring when array index goes out of bounds

Tags: python, matrix, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to index a lot of python matrices to carry out calculations (mainly dot products) on corresponding elements.
I'm having a problem using the non-zero values of one matrix to index a matrix that has fewer columns - it throws errors saying the index is out of bounds.
Is there a way for me to tell python not to care about when the index is out of bounds - to ignore those ones and just deal with the ones that are in bounds?
The code is something  like this:

```
for u in range (n): # u = row:
    U[R[u,:]!=0, u] ...
```

the dimension of U is (dxn) and dimension of R is (nxm) where m > n > d (usually).

I was hoping there is something built in in python to ignore when the index is out of bounds?

Comment: No you'd have to do `len(...)` first to check the length or use a `try / except` case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to exception handle 'list index out of range.'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902458/i-want-to-exception-handle-list-index-out-of-range)

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that I could find the shape of the matrix U and use it to put a bound on the indexing of R like follows:

```
n,m = U.shape
U[R[u,0:n]!=0, u]
```

this means it never goes out of bounds as we're only looking at the part of R that is in the bounds of U