# Function input outside the matrix

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matrix

I am writing a function with the parameters `d` and `e`. `d` represents a matrix that the user inputs, and `e` represents the starting position in the matrix. I was able to define `e` as the position of the matrix `d`:

```
mainIndex = e[0]
secondIndex = e[1]
position = d[row][column]
```

I have a challenge whereby if the user inputs the position outside of the matrix the user inputted, it returns `False`; for instance, if the matrix `d = [[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]]` and `e = [3,0]`, it should return `False` rather than raising an `index out of range` error. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to catch the error as follows:

```
mainIndex = e[0]
secondIndex = e[1]
try:
    position = d[row][column]
except IndexError:
    return False
```

Source: [I want to exception handle 'list index out of range.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902458/i-want-to-exception-handle-list-index-out-of-range)

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without try and except feature? I'm taking an online introduction to programming course and we were supposed to complete that question with things we have learned (if-statements, loops, basic list methods and simple methods/helper functions)

Comment: You could always check if the requested index is greater than the length of the list. For example:

`index=4
if index > len(a):
    print('This index is out of range')`. It is usually accepted in python to [try first and ask for acceptance later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first).

Answer (score 1):

#### `try` / `except`

You can write a function and catch `IndexError`. I would also advise you don't chain indexers but use `arr[row, column]` syntax. For example:

```
d = np.array([[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]])

def get_val(A, idx):
    try:
        return A[tuple(idx)]
    except IndexError:
        return False

e = [3, 0]
f = [0, 2]

get_val(d, e)  # False
get_val(d, f)  # 1
```

#### `if` / `else`

An alternative, more explicit solution, is possible via an `if` / `else` construct:

```
def get_val(A, idx):
    if all(i < j for i, j in zip(idx, A.shape)):
        return A[tuple(idx)]
    return False
```

Since we use `tuple(idx)`, both solutions work for arbitrary dimensions.