# Python function that will read a specific line in a .txt file

Tags: python

**Goal:** Function that will read a specific line in a .txt file.

Example .txt file used is five lines long with each line stating "First line", "Second Line", and so on down to "Firth Line".

The function I have so far will read the line as indicated by the `line_number` argument when 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 is passed through it, but results in an `index error` if the argument is any integer >=5 since these are blank/empty on the .txt file. I would like the function to return `"Empty Line"` when a `line_number` argument is used that would read a blank/empty line.

**Function:**

```
def txtfile_line(file_path: str,line_number: int):
    open_file = open(file_path)
    read_file = open_file.readlines()
    if read_file[line_number] == '\n':
        return ("Empty Line")
    else:
        return read_file[line_number]
    
print(txtfile_line("file.txt",5))
```

Current Output `IndexError: list index out of range` if the argument entered is a blank line

Goal Output `"Empty Cell"` if the argument entered is a blank line

**.txt file used:**

```
First line
Second line
Third line
Fourth line
Fifth line
```

Comment: You should check `line_number >= len(read_file)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to exception handle 'list index out of range.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902458/i-want-to-exception-handle-list-index-out-of-range)

Comment: As stated, if your file is "5 lines long", then there are only that many lines, and no empty lines, so unclear how you think it is _"since these are blank/empty on the .txt file"_. That being said, IndexError is a valid exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong indexing -->

sample file im using:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

```
def txtfile_line(file_path: str,line_number: int):
    open_file = open(file_path)
    read_file = open_file.readlines()
    if line_number > len(read_file):
        return ("invalid index")
    if read_file[line_number-1] == '\n':
        return ("Empty Line")
    else:
        return read_file[line_number - 1]

print(txtfile_line("file.txt",5))
```

```
5
```

when running `print(txtfile_line("file.txt",6))` this modified function will give

```
invalid index
```

remember that list indexes start at 0, so a list with a length of 5 would actually be indexed 0-4!

Comment: "6" was just an example, I would want it to work for any integer entered into the 2nd argument that would result in and empty/blank line.

Comment: would you want an index over that of the length of the actual file to return blank or an error?

Comment: your edited version with a len(read_file) worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, well the code you gave me works as is. Remember that the line number starts at 0 not 1. You could be inputting a line that actually isn't there.

Also you'll want to change this:

```
if read_file[line_number] == "\\n": #Double backslash lets the compiler know its not a special character.
     ...
```

EDIT:
I see, I misread the question. Here's a simple fix:

```
if len(read_file) <= line_number:
    return ("Empty Line")
```

Comment: How does this fix `IndexError`?

Comment: also, i belive he *does* want to check for a special character

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_txt_line(file_path: str, line_number: int) -> str:
    try:
        open_file = open(file_path)
        read_file = open_file.readlines()
        return "Empty Line" if read_file[line_number - 1] == '\n' else read_file[line_number - 1]
    except IndexError:
        return "Empty Line"
    except FileNotFoundError as file_error:
        return str(file_error)


# Case 1 : wrong file
print(read_txt_line("data/testm.txt", 6))
# output : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/testm.txt'

# Case 2 : correct
print(read_txt_line("data/test.txt", 5))
# output : Fifth line

# Case 3 : line number beyond text file content
print(read_txt_line("data/test.txt", 6))
# output : Empty Line
```

**test.txt** file content

```
First line
Second line
Third line
Fourth line
Fifth line
```